# Was Ben Beckman based on the real-world pirate Henry Avery?

Tags: one-piece

I was talking to my friend about how Oda likes to name and base pirates in *One Piece* after real-world pirates. I have always thought that Gold Roger was based on the real-world pirate Oliver Levasseur, but my friend thought that he was based on the pirate who was considered the pirate king in the real-world, Henry Avery.

I decided to research a bit about Avery after this and I found out that his crew used to refer to him as Long Ben or Benjamin Bridgeman which is extremely similar to Ben Beckman of the red-haired pirates.

Is it just a coincidence or am I on to something?

Comment: This is just speculation and a case can be made for different sources that Oda uses. He hasn't answered as such in SBS to conclusively prove who is Ben Beckman inspired from. Some people for example speculate he is based on Johann Beckman [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Beckmann] because he has the highest IQ in East Blue (atleast) For more canon information, I'd suggest you read Oda's SBS

Comment: @Arcane just because the author does not state his sources does not mean the question is subjective. It just means that the objective information required to answer it is hard to acquire. We don't peg the quality of the question on the ease of answerability. This question can have an objective answer.

Comment: From review: I am voting to leave this question open.

Comment: He is, it was revealed in some SBS can't remember which though